# HttpClient, Make Action String Type Safe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, httpclient, angular10

Is there anyway to make the 'post' action string type safe below? Right now it accepts Any word to substitute in for `'post'`,  example `'abcd'`, will Not create compilation error.

**Example:**

```
 saveUsers(body?: UpdateIdentityUserDto): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.request<IdentityUserDtoBaseRequestResponse>('post',`${this.baseUserUrl}`,
        {
            body: body
        }
    );
  }
```

**Option:**

Here is another option below, however, I prefer to use string option above since those are auto generated from Swagger IO proxy generator.

```
saveUsers(body?: UpdateIdentityUserDto): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post<IdentityUserDtoBaseRequestResponse>(`${this.baseUserUrl}`,body);
}
```

Currently using Angular 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest wrapping it around and making it a generic method. Make a separate file for these generics.

```
type HttpMethods = 'post' | 'get' | 'patch' | 'delete';

request<T>(method: HttpMethods, body: any): Observable<any> {
    this.httpClient.request<T>(method, this.baseUrl, { body: body });
}
```

Then if you want to make a call an api call in a separate file, call this

```
import { request } from '...'

saveUsers(body?: BodyInterface): Observable<ResponseInterface> {
    return request<IdentityUserDtoBaseRequestResponse>('post', body)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `namespace` and export constants for the different types of request methods.

```
export namespace RequestMethod {

  export const GET:string = "get";

  export const HEAD:string = "head";

  export const POST:string = "post";

  export const PUT:string = "put";

  export const DELETE:string = "delete";

  export const CONNECT:string = "connect";

  export const OPTIONS:string = "options";

  export const TRACE:string = "trace";

  export const PATCH:string = "patch";

}
```

Then you can utilize this namespace inside of a `service`

```
import { RequestMethod } from '../request-method.ts';

saveUsers(body?: UpdateIdentityUserDto): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.request<IdentityUserDtoBaseRequestResponse>(RequestMethod.POST,`${this.baseUserUrl}`,
        {
            body: body
        }
    );
  }
```

Understand that this does not prevent a developer from typing any string they want. But it does give you a type-safe way of ensuring your strings are consistent through the app when utilized as a standard within your team.